# Istio ingress gw

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I running istio 1.3 .
Created with helm chat istio igreess gw in namespace test.
If I put the istio ingress gw in some another name space ( rather that istio-system) I got in the istio-proxy log: Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 0 rejected . Did someone encounter this problem?
If I run istioctl proxy-status the envoy is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the Ingress Gateway pod.

Seems this have been already mentioned on GitHub [here](http://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11039) and [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13863).

Also you can try getting more information about the issue as it was mentioned by @[GregHanson](https://github.com/GregHanson) in his [comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13863#issuecomment-490084227).

> Also check the logs of the ingress gateway to see if it rejected a listener
>
> ```
> kubectl logs -n istio-system -l istio=ingressgateway | grep -v deprecated
> ```
>
> Also verify which listeners the ingress gateway does know about:
>
> ```
> istioctl proxy-config listeners <istio_ingressgateway_pod>.istio-system
> ```
>
> Then, check the logs of istio-pilot for any errors related that may have occurred for the host/port defined in the Gateway.
>
> ```
> kubectl logs -n istio-system <istio_pilot_pod> discovery
> ```

Comment: Hi, What you mention it's another issue. This is when you want to create gw and vs to existing istio gw. I try to create a new istio gw . I put the new istio gw not in istio-system namespace like was before (that working) I put it in another namespace and got error that enovy cant connect to pilot.

Comment: Update your question with logs and steps so we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: You can reproduce it very simple try to create istio gateway gateway and virtual service in another namespace (than istio-system)  like house and see if all working